# Recurrence for integral $I_{n}=\int_{0}^{1}x^{n}\sqrt{1-x^2}\: dx$

Tags: real-analysis, integration

If $$I_{n}=\int_{0}^{1}x^{n}\sqrt{1-x^2}\: dx$$
show that $$(n+2)I_{n}=(n-1)I_{n-2}$$
Ok, here is what I've tried $$I_{n}=\int_{0}^{1}x^{n-1}x\sqrt{1-x^2}\:dx$$ and the I use integration by parts with $x\sqrt{1-x^2}=(-\frac{1}{3}\sqrt{(1-x^2)^3})^{'}$ wich gives me problems with that $-\frac{1}{3}$. This is one of my aproaches, the other ones are in this method, with integration by parts. But nothing. Also, I need a solution without using gamma function.

Comment: Could you at least tell us what approaches you've tried?

Comment: Yes, I can, but not right now cause I'm not home and it s not easy to go on the phone

Comment: Try integrating $\int_0^1x^n\sqrt{1-x^2}\,\mathrm{d}x=-\frac13\int_0^1x^{n-1}\,\mathrm{d}\sqrt{1-x^2}^3$ by parts

Comment: Please don't tell us to not tell you to share the own thoughts, 'cause we are so many...

Answer (score 2):

Integrate by parts instead as follows

\begin{align}
(n+2) I_n &= (n+2)\int_0^1 x^n \sqrt{1-x^2} \;dx \\
&= -\int_0^1 x^{n-1}{(1-x^2)^{\frac{1-n}2}}\ d\left[(1-x^2)^{\frac{n+2}2}\right]\\
&= -x^{n-1}(1-x^2)^{3/2}\bigg|_0^1
+(n-1)\int_0^1 x^{n-2} \sqrt{1-x^2} \;dx \\
&=  (n-1)I_{n-2}
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

We may use immediately the beta function,

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function

directly or indirectly after the substitution $x=\sin t$,
then obtain the wanted relation by passing to the gamma function and using its functional equation $\Gamma(x+1)=x\Gamma(x)$:
$$
\begin{aligned}
I_n
&=
\int_0^1 x^n(1-x^2)^{1/2}\; dx
\\
&=
\int_0^{\pi/2}\sin^n t\; \cos^2 t\; dt
\\
&=
\frac 12B\left(\frac{n+1}2,\; \frac{2+1}2\right)
\\
&=
\frac 12
\frac
{
\Gamma\left(\frac{n+1}2\right)
\Gamma\left(\frac{2+1}2\right)}
{
\Gamma\left(\frac{n+4}2\right)
}
\\
&=
\frac 12
\frac
{
\color{blue}{\frac{n-1}2}
\Gamma\left(\frac{n-1}2\right)
\Gamma\left(\frac{2+1}2\right)}
{
\color{blue}{\frac{n+2}2}
\Gamma\left(\frac{n+2}2\right)
}
\\
&=
\color{blue}{\frac{n-1}{n+2}}
I_{n-2}\ .
\end{aligned}
$$

Comment: If we are going to use an explicit solution using the Beta function, we don't really need a recurrence. All that is really needed for the recurrence is integration by parts; a lot less machinery.

Comment: There are some vestigial $B$s in lines $4$ and $5$.

Comment: @robjohn This was important, i am always grateful for such hints, the only way to avoid my systematic errors. (I have to see them explicitly and make a knot in my mind to have one more check in similar cases.) Thanks a lot!